# Block Youtube on the Network But Still Access Specific Videos

Tags: networking, web-applications, filter, youtube, youtube-api

Scenario: Business would like to block youtube.com, but still serve approved videos through a desktop application or website. Is there a way to block people from youtube.com but still serve the video traffic through an embedded player or  chromeless player in a desktop application?

Maybe a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use youtube-dl sh script to download approved videos and just host on your own page as mp4 or flv and block access to youtube itself.
  http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/

Comment: That's actually a very interesting solution, I would have to also create a uploader...

My other option may be to install something like Safewall and have it check an approved list from a remote database. Does that seem viable?